# Prevent Electron app from redirecting when drag+dropping items in window

Tags: javascript, electron

I don't want a `drag+drop` feature in my app since there is no need for it. So I want to completely remove the `drag+drop` feature of the window. So far when dragging images the Electron window opens the image path. When dragging links the Electron window redirects to the link.

I have tried calling this:

```
  document.addEventListener('dragstart',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  },true);

  document.addEventListener('drop',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  },true);
```

`event.preventDefault()` on the `drop event` should have worked but it didn't

Also tried [this](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1965#issuecomment-111719974):

```
  BrowserWindow.on('will-navigate',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  BrowserWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
```

Also failed. Any ideas how to fix this?

[removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) failed as well

```
  var listener = function (event) {
    console.log('foo');
  };
  document.removeEventListener('drop',listener,false);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be targeting the element you want to attach the event listener to via id/class? Also wouldn't you want to use `removeEventlistener()` since you want to remove the event?

Comment: The function used for the drag event, is it an external function? I believe removeEventListener will only work for external function. If so, do you know what the function is called. "The one used to make the element draggable"

Comment: You're trying to cancel a function by targeting event listeners so that tells me some event listener is trigger a function to do something, hence wanting to cancel/overwrite it. I'm asking you if you if the function is an external function or attached to an event listener.

Comment: Ah I see! Well I don't think I can be of any help. I wish you luck with finding a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a fix for <strike>Windows Electron v2.3.1</strike> `Windows Electron v0.30.0` the code should have listeners for both `dragover` AND `drop`.

```
  document.addEventListener('dragover',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  },false);

  document.addEventListener('drop',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  },false);
```

Electron will still redirect to the dropped file if you only listen to `dragover` or `drop`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 13):

A concise version using ES6 syntax (working for me under Electron 1.4.1)

```
document.addEventListener('dragover', event => event.preventDefault())
document.addEventListener('drop', event => event.preventDefault())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple css in render process.

```
        *, *::after, *::before {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
        cursor: default;
    }
```